# Issues in running query on json datatype regarding ':' element

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update

I am creating a PostgreSQL query to translate a sentence text to it's native language, given below:

```
update translation_table 
   set json = jsonb_set(json, '{Hindi}', (json->>'Hindi')::jsonb|| '{"1 : hello":"1 : नमस्ते"}'::jsonb, true)  
where type='translate'
```

But on output I'm getting no result. This is happening only if I provide `:` inside the json element, otherwise the query is giving desired output if I remove the `:`.
Please let me know how can I escape this special character issue?

Comment: You are running an UPDATE with no RETURNING clause.  What output are you expecting to get?

Comment: output as in getting the updated result while showing the data of the table

Comment: Please show us a complete example, including the starting value.  The problem is probably in your starting value.  colons do not require any special handling, they just have to be in double quotes along with the rest of the string they are in.

Comment: Also, please restrict your example to ASCII characters, unless the non-ASCII nature is important to the question.  It will make it easier for others to test your example.